# Sphinx search numbers with prefixes

Tags: sphinx

How to query words with prefixes and suffixes in Sphinx?

I have such fields

```
"Value544"
"Some value"
"544"
"Some544value"
```

So "value" gets to me only "Some value", "544" - only "544". I want Sphinx with query "544" also gets me "Value544" and "Some544value".

Here is my source config:

```
    docinfo             = extern
    html_strip          = 1
    min_word_len        = 1
    min_infix_len       = 2
#    min_prefix_len      = 1
    morphology          = metaphone, stem_en, libstemmer_sv, libstemmer_german, soundex
    charset_type        = utf-8
    enable_star         = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

blend_chars might be able to do it,

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-blend-chars

but I have never tried.

---

Although your min_infix_len should do it anyway. I suspect your morphology is causing issue. As only one fires on a given word, mixing and matching like that is not recommended. (eg mixing metaphone, and stemming in one index. You have soundex in there too, which is bound to mess things up. )

Comment: I need to use different morphology. But even if I set morphology = none or even remove morphology, it won't search properly.

Comment: Are you completely rebuilding your index after changing the settings?

Comment: Sure: indexer --all --rotate

Comment: Ah, just noticesd yoy  have enable_star in there too. So would need to include stars in the query. Remove that so you dont have to.

Comment: After removing of enable_star=1 I get infixes and morphology are enabled, enable_star=0. If I set morphology=none, fuzzy search stop to work and I can get search by words part also.

Answer (score 0):

You should use star symbol(`*`). For example, with your index configuration, you query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM your_index WHERE MATCH('*577*');
```